# coalesce not giving the desired output in R

Tags: r, dplyr

Here is my toy data

```
data <- data.frame(x = c("a","b",NA,NA,NA),
                   y = c(NA,NA,"c",NA,NA),
                   z = c(NA,NA,NA,"d","NA"))
```

and, here is my sample code:

```
library(tidyverse)

output <- data %>% mutate(mycol = coalesce(x,y,z)) 

desired_output <- data.frame(x = c("a","b",NA,NA,NA),
                   y = c(NA,NA,"c",NA,NA),
                   z = c(NA,NA,NA,"d","NA"),
                   mycol = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "NA"))
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: try `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`

Comment: @Geet: This works with `R 4.0.0`

Comment: Thanks Tung for letting me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the type from factor to produce the desired result:

```
> data %>% mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) %>% mutate(mycol = coalesce(x,y,z)) 
     x    y    z mycol
1    a <NA> <NA>     a
2    b <NA> <NA>     b
3 <NA>    c <NA>     c
4 <NA> <NA>    d     d
5 <NA> <NA>   NA    NA
```